# How to set up content assist in Eclipse on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse

When I type code in Sublime say, I just need to start with the first few letters of some variables and it would come up with a list of possible existing variable names that match what I just typed. But in Eclipse, I don't know how to realize this. In the preference-java-editor-content assist, I found this auto-activation pane and according to some other posts, I'm supposed to change the auto activation triggers for java. However this is how my default setting looks like. I don't understand the dot over there. Also I'm not sure if that's the right way to approach my problem?

Can someone help me out? Thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The auto activation will give you suggestions about fields and methods that are available. For example if you start typing in

`new Object().`

then the IDE (Eclipse) will give you suggestions (after 200ms from the "Auto activation delay") of `toString()`, `equals()`, and other methods.

If you just want to use plain auto-complete, I tend to use the shortcut `CTRL`+ `Space` (The spacebar key). So if I want Eclipse to auto-complete a method name for me  (say the method is `reallyLongMethodNameIDoNotWantToTypeOut()`) I'll type in

`reallyL` press `CTRL` + `Space` and Eclipse will fill in the rest for me.

Comment: Thanks! I'm thinking of auto-complete a long method name. But I'm using Mac so Ctrl+space doesn't work for me. I believe I had the content assist  in Eclipse set up to some keybinding. But when I copy paste this reallyLongMethodNameIDoNotWantToTypeOut() and then try to type it again using the "auto-complete" way, it says "no default proposals"...

Comment: it'll only autocomplete actual methods not previous "chunks of text" like Sublime. Basically field names, class names, methods. If you just type a different string it will not offer autocomplete for that.

Comment: Thanks! So basically there's no way I can ask Eclipse to suggest variable names? I still don't think it is even suggesting method name. Say there's a string method called equalsIgnoreCase() but even if I type equals... I see nothing coming up and I have to finish it by myself...

Comment: If you're using it for java it should be suggesting already defined fields, for example if you have `int myFieldName` and start typing in `myFi` and do CTRL+Space, it should bring up or complete `myFieldName`. But it won't suggest based on a text-type search alone, just on actual class related elements.